# SignalR backplane and databaseinput?

Tags: database, signalr, signalr-backplane

We have a load balanced webserver setup and we therefore want to use SignalR for client/server communication with a SignalR backplane.

How can we make sure that only one server writes to the database when a client sends something to the server? The backplane will re-route the message to all servers, but not all servers can write the same thing to the DB!

Any techniques/suggestions for how I can both use the SignalR backplane and only write to DB from one server?

In my ideal world I would receive the message on one server, store message to DB and then put a message (maybe not the same as the incoming message) on to the backplane.

Comment: If a client sends something to a server, wouldn't only one server be handling any given message? How is there a risk of all servers writing the same thing to the DB in this scenario?

Comment: The SignalR backplane will forward the message to all servers, i.e. not only to the server that first receives the message from the client. And I don't think there is a way for the servers to know if the message originated to them and therefore they won't know who should write to the DB.

Comment: The SignalR backplane only forwards messages sent *from the server to client* to all servers. This is done so SignalR can ensure messages will get to their intended client(s) even if they hop servers. When a SignalR client invokes a Hub method, the Hub method is only invoked on one server even if there are multiple SignalR servers behind a load balancer communicating via a backplane.

Comment: OK, I've misunderstood the use of the backplane! Do you want to write some kind of answer explaining this? So that my original question gets an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SignalR backplane only forwards messages sent *from the server to client* to all servers. This is done so SignalR can ensure messages will get to their intended client(s) even if they are connected to another server.

When a SignalR client invokes a Hub method, the Hub method is only invoked on one server even if there are multiple SignalR servers behind a load balancer communicating via a backplane.